# Kotlin, Dagger, Nullable and Named cannot find value to @Inject

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have a property that is type String?. I am able to @Inject the value fine until I try to add an @Named attribute to the property. Everything also works fine if I use a 'String' instead of the nullable String, but the value is nullable, so I need the '?'.

In my module, I have:

```
@Provides
@Named("someStringOrNull")
fun provideSomeStringOrNull(): String? = "STRING OR NULL"
```

In my activity, I have:

```
@set:Inject
@set:Named("someStringOrNull")
var someStringOrNull: String? = null
```

and I get this error:

```
Error:(11, 2) error: java.lang.String cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
public abstract void inject(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                     ^
  java.lang.String is injected at
      com.scrawlsoft.daggerwoes.MainActivity.setSomeStringOrNull(p0)
  com.scrawlsoft.daggerwoes.MainActivity is injected at
      com.scrawlsoft.daggerwoes.AppComponent.inject(target)
```

This works fine if I remove the @Named attr, so I'm fairly certain that the '@set:' is correct, but I could be mistaken.

Any suggestions on how to make this work? (At the moment, I am considering wrapping this in a custom class so that I don't need the @Named, but that seems wasteful to me.)

Full source code can be found at: https://github.com/gmadrid/DaggerWoes/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/scrawlsoft/daggerwoes

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does Kotlin/Dagger work with typealias yet? That might solve my problem.

Comment: I can't remember anymore, but I think I encountered something similar and actually had to use ``field``. Did you try ``@field:Named("someStringOrNull")`` instead of ``@set:Named("someStringOrNull")``?

Comment: Yes. `@field` doesn't work with native types because the underlying field is marked 'private'. That's why I moved the attribute to the setter with `@set`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to use `@JvmField` to instruct the Kotlin compiler to expose your property as a field instead of generating getter/setter:

```
@Inject
@JvmField
@field:Named("someStringOrNull")
internal var someStringOrNull: String? = null
```